# XSLT code to insert segment under parent segment

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I have a input XML document in which need to move few segments under parent segment with condition `<c>` should come under `<b>` segment when `<b2>` is "8R" only. For other segments `<e>` and `<f>` there is no condition, just need to move under `<d>`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ns0:TEST_Report xmlns:ns0="urn:abc">
   <Record>
      <a>
         <a1>123</a1>
         <a2>11</a2>
      </a>
      <b>
         <b1>23</b1>
         <b2>SJ</b2>
      </b>
      <b>
         <b1>67</b1>
         <b2>8S</b2>
      </b>
      <b>
         <b1>90</b1>
         <b2>8R</b2>
      </b>
      <c>
         <c1>asd</c1>
         <c2>2342445435346</c2>
      </c>
      <c>
         <c1>wsx</c1>
         <c2>8798987978</c2>
      </c>
      <d>
         <d1>XYZ</d1>
         <d2>cvb</d2>
      </d>
      <e>
         <e1>1212</e1>
      </e>
      <e>
         <e1>4321</e1>
      </e>
      <f>
         <f1>11</f1>
         <f2>11</f2>
      </f>
      <f>
         <f1>133</f1>
         <f2>1133</f2>
      </f>
      <f>
         <f1>1345</f1>
         <f2>54434</f2>
      </f>
      <d>
         <d1>XYZ</d1>
         <d2>cvb</d2>
      </d>
      <e>
         <e1>1212</e1>
      </e>
      <f>
         <f1>11</f1>
         <f2>11</f2>
      </f>
      <f>
         <f1>133</f1>
         <f2>1133</f2>
      </f>
   </Record>
</ns0:TEST_Report>
```

XSLT code i have tried:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:ns0="urn:abc">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="TEST_Report">
        <ns0:TEST_Report>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </ns0:TEST_Report>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="B">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::C[1]"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="C">
        <xsl:if test="preceding-sibling::B[3]">
            <xsl:copy>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
            </xsl:copy>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Required Output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ns0:TEST_Report xmlns:ns0="urn:abc">
   <Record>
      <a>
         <a1>123</a1>
         <a2>11</a2>
      </a>
      <b>
         <b1>23</b1>
         <b2>SJ</b2>
      </b>
      <b>
         <b1>67</b1>
         <b2>8S</b2>
      </b>
      <b>
         <b1>90</b1>
         <b2>8R</b2>
         <c>
            <c1>asd</c1>
            <c2>2342445435346</c2>
         </c>
         <c>
            <c1>wsx</c1>
            <c2>8798987978</c2>
         </c>
      </b>
      <d>
         <d1>XYZ</d1>
         <d2>cvb</d2>
         <e>
            <e1>1212</e1>
         </e>
         <e>
            <e1>4321</e1>
         </e>
         <f>
            <f1>11</f1>
            <f2>11</f2>
         </f>
         <f>
            <f1>133</f1>
            <f2>1133</f2>
         </f>
         <f>
            <f1>1345</f1>
            <f2>54434</f2>
         </f>
      </d>
      <d>
         <d1>XYZ</d1>
         <d2>cvb</d2>
         <e>
            <e1>1212</e1>
         </e>
         <f>
            <f1>11</f1>
            <f2>11</f2>
         </f>
         <f>
            <f1>133</f1>
            <f2>1133</f2>
         </f>
      </d>
   </Record>
</ns0:TEST_Report>
```

Kindly help to achieve this using xslt 1.0 code. I have tried few other codes as well but it is not working for this requirement.

Comment: XPath is case-sensitive. You are showing lower-case elements, but your match expression is matching upper-case elements, so that's one problem.

Comment: Is it possible for an input to contain a `c` element when no `b` element contains `<b2>8R</b2>`? Or to contain `e` or `f` elements without a `d` preceding them?

Comment: And is the requirement really about that `b` having a `<b2>8R</b2>` or just that it's the last `b`?

Comment: Thank you for your reply @michael.hor257k , it worked for me!! The requirement is for 8R segment and c element won't come without b element contains <b2>8R</b2>. Similarly, e and f elements won't come without d element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is more complicated than it might seem - not because of the condition on `b`, but because you have more than one `d` element, each with its own "tail" of `e` and `f` elements.

From the context of the first `d`, **all** subsequent `e` and `f` elements are on the `following-sibling` axis - regardless of any "intervening" `d` elements placed along the way. So basically you are looking for an XSLT 1.0 implementation of `group-starting-with`, which could be handled as:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:key name="c" match="c" use="generate-id(preceding-sibling::b[b2='8R'][1])" />
<xsl:key name="ef" match="e|f" use="generate-id(preceding-sibling::d[1])" />

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="b[b2='8R']">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:copy-of select="*"/>
        <xsl:copy-of select="key('c', generate-id())"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="d">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:copy-of select="*"/>
        <xsl:copy-of select="key('ef', generate-id())"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="c[preceding-sibling::b[1]/b2='8R'] | e | f"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

---

If every `c` has a preceding sibling `b` that contains `<b2>8R</b2>`, then you can simplify the last template to:

```
<xsl:template match="c|e|f"/>
```